# jquery after i submit a form the second one just posts to page instead of ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok basically my problem is what i stated in the title. I'm using jquery tabs and after i submit 1 form and i go about adding another news post instead of doing the ajax submit it just posts to the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit').live("click",function () {     
        //Get the data from all the fields
        var title = $('input[name=title]').val();
        var newspost = tinyMCE.get('newspost').getContent();
        var type = $('input[name=type]').val();

        //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
        //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field 

        //organize the data properly
        var data = 'title=' + title + '&post=' + newspost + '&id=' + type;
        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "pages/news.php",  

            //GET method is used
            type: "POST",

            //pass the data         
            data: data,     

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

            //success
 success: function() {  
     $('#news_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
     $('#message').html("<h2>News Article has been Submitted!</h2>")  
     .append("<p>Now visable on main page</p>")  
     .hide()  
     .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
       $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");  
     });  
            }       
        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    }); 
 </script>
<div id="news_form">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>Title:
    <label>
      <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="40" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <textarea name="newspost" id="newspost" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p><input type="hidden" name="type" value="postadd" />
    <label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning false won't prevent the default action; try [event.preventDefault](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) instead.

Comment: Same thing happend. When i went to submit a second news posting it just posted to the page instead of doing the ajax submit.

Comment: Hmmmm, can you post a complete example? Ideally a pared-down one that only has what you need to replicate the problem?

Comment: I'll setup a test directory on my site so you can see for yourself..give me a few mins

Comment: http://wildhivefarm.com/test username=demo password=demo if anyone cares to see it working....

Comment: I was going to delete this answer (as it's wrong), but I'll leave it so the link remains. But see ScottE's answer, I expect he's sussed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried listening for the .submit() event on the form itself?

Also, make sure you don't have duplicate ids on the page.

Comment: Ack! I missed that! It's hooked to the submit button's click event. That's got to be the problem.

Comment: so would it $('#form1').submit( function ?

Comment: put it in, worked the first time, then when i clicked it for the second time it did what it normally do, just regular post to the page instead of the ajax call

Comment: figured it out. I have TinyMCE as an editor..that seems to be messing it up

Comment: So it was throwing an error, preventing your scripts from running?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness you might consider the following:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
if ($.browser.msie) {
    event.originalEvent.keyCode = 0;
    event.originalEvent.cancelBubble = true;
    event.originalEvent.returnValue = false;
}
```

Although I'm in a bit af a quandry as I would normally encourage feature detection ablve browser sniffing (`if ($.browser.msie) {...`)

Also, noticed your first line:

```
$('#submit').live("click",function () {
```

Although it probably won't make a difference, I can't see how you require live(). Surely .click() ought to suffice?

Comment: I added that, and now when i go for the second submit it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: put what into the body of .fadein ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your submit button to a regular button.  You don't need the default submit behavior if you're handling it with AJAX.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Or, if you want to keep it as-is, you should put the return false in your click function, not inside the AJAX success function.

Comment: Same problem..still stalls after the second one

Comment: Are you sure there's no JavaScript errors that are preventing future script from executing?

Answer (score 0):

I have tinyMCE installed an my editor. Once I removed it I was able to post as many times in a row as I wanted.